# how to implode CkStringArray like php?

Tags: visual-c++, chilkat, vc90

is **Chilkatsoft** has implode function of `CkStringArray` if not then how can we combine all `CkStringArray` members and get a `CkString` object

```
CkString implode(char* key, CkStringArray* StrArray) {
    CkString rt;
    CkString tmp;
    for (int i = 0; i < StrArray->get_Length(); i++) {
        tmp.clear();
        StrArray->Pop(tmp);
        rt.append(tmp);
        if (i < (StrArray->get_Length() - 1))
            rt.append(key);
    }
    tmp.clear();
    return rt;
}
```

Referenced as:

```
CkString abc = "h|e|l|l|o";
CkStringArray* cba = abc.split('|',true,false,false);
MessageBox(NULL, (LPCSTR)implode2("-",cba).getString(), NULL, NULL);
```

then gives in messagebox *o-l-l*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ChilkSoft** not provide implode function. use `GetString` instead of `Pop` like follows:

```
CkString implode(char* key, CkStringArray* StrArray) {
    CkString rt;
    CkString tmp;
    for (int i = 0; i < StrArray->get_Length(); i++) {
        tmp.clear();
        StrArray->GetString(i, tmp);
        rt.append(tmp.getString());
        if (i < (StrArray->get_Length() - 1))
            rt.append(key);
    }
    tmp.clear();
    return rt;
}
```